# Determination of the electric and magnetic field of a beam of protons as functions of the distance $r$ to the beam with the help of Ampere and Gauss

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields, gauss-law

I want to calculate the fields $\vec{E},\vec{B}$ as a function of $r$.
I know that the current implied by the beam is $I=env_{p},v_p=\frac{c}{3}$ and the charge density is $\rho=en$.
On top of that, the beam of protons is moving along the $x$-direction with velocity $v_p=\frac{c}{3}$ and the beam is of density $n$ protons per unit length.

I want to find $\vec{B}$ with the help of Ampere's law:
$$\oint_{S}\vec{B}\cdot d\vec{s}=\mu_0 I_{in},$$
where $I_{in}$ is the current enclosed by $S$.

And I want to find $\vec{E}$ with the help of Gauss's law:
$$\int_{\partial V}\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{A}=\int_V \text{div}\vec{E}dV=\frac{1}{\varepsilon_0}\int_V\rho dV.$$

I am having trouble with determining the symmetries of the problem and the correct terms for the integrals...

Thanks for help!

Comment: Do you know if you're allowed to assume it to be an infinitely long beam or long enough for us to use that approximation because if so you would be able to use the fact that in cylindrical coordiantes if the beam is in the z direction that translations in z would not lead to a change in the charge density as it is constant hence the electric field is not a function of z. If we reflect in the same direction then the charge density also doesn't change hence the electric field has no z component. If we repeat this logic for  $\phi$ then we can determine the electric field

Comment: electric field to also not be a function of $\phi$ nor have a component in that direction hence due to symmetry (cylindrical to be precise) the electric field is $\vec{E}(r)=E_r\vec{\hat{r}}$

Comment: Thanks! With the help of your comment I realized that I can make these assumptions. Now it is clear!